# Android, are there any APIs to read mail from a mailbox (local/web)?

Tags: java, android, email, imap, pop3

I'm working on a small app to verify a 3rd party mail service uptime. The app is intended to send out mail at regular intervals using 3rd party, then read mail from a mailbox to ensure delivery. If there's no message received for a certain period of time, the IT team is notified of email outage. Once the messages go through again, the IT team is notified that the service has been resumed.

**I'm trying to understand what are my options for accessing email messages from an Android device.** Is there a way to read the local mailbox content? If no, can anyone suggest a java library for email pickup from a remote server?

Thank you!

Comment: Wait, you are developing an application _on a phone_ that is to be used for monitoring? What if the phone is off or not in a service area?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There aren't any APIs, because Android doesn't require the user to depend on Gmail (or any other mail service) for mail. If you're talking about pinging a web-based mail service, then you have to use that mail service's APIs from your Android. Many web-based apps have one (or more) APIs based on HTTP, and Android supports HTTP.

You may need to write an Android app that either implements or access the local mailbox.

Before struggling through the Java libraries, I'd start with the available APIs for your email service.